# Learning WPF without success

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello developers and designers,

I am very willing to learn WPF in which i use C# as the logic code.
Or i 'try' to anyway.

I have written a 2-page long code-behind in Forms-style though, so i know *some* syntaxes.
But that was a really cumbersome way of doing it.

The problem is that i am still lingering around the area of understanding at least the basic concept of object oriented programming. But 9 out of 10 times i am not getting the example-codes entirely because of that '1 little thing of which i don't even know what it's called'.
How do you even know if there is a command for the function you want to express and more importantly.... how it's called and where it located in what namespace?

Even the best video-examples aren't doing it for me, because when any code is typed, they never explain how the code exactly works. And most of the times it just doesn't even add up to what i know of logic code (of course i'm wrong).

In the early days i learned the Commodore64's Basic no problem.
Learning and writing Actionscript (Flash), within 2 months creating a 2D-shoot'em up
Learning and writing CMD, within 3 months writing 5000+ lines of code for all sorts of functions.

Why in Merlin's beard is WPF so hard?
Watching the "simplest" tutorial-video's are becoming more and more de-motivational.

Anyone recognizes this?

Thanks for reading,
Danny

Comment: personally I'd learn c# and OOP before jumping into WPF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding WPF the articles I've found to be most useful are the overviews on MSDN, they might take quite some time to work through but they are concise and in-depth, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) for a master-overview.

Why WPF is hard is a good question, one primary cause might be that it is simply huge, at least i perceive it that way. Aside from having all the code you also now have XAML markup which is a world of its own.

Someone from Microsoft who did a presentation on F# in 2008 said that if you know three of the keywords, `let`, `fun` & `|>`, you know the whole language, which is not even that much of an overstatement. WPF on the other hand is *not a language*, it is a sub-framework. If F# can be likened to 3 nanotechnology building blocks then WPF is a 50 meter workbench stacked with tools (the controls) and a dozen heavy duty machines (WPF mechanisms like [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), [commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx), [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), etc.), and all of those come with a manual. So if you are facing a problem you pretty much need to know what all the tools and machines do so you know which to use, and then of course you also need to know *how* to use them, apart from their basic functionality each may even have its own kinks and peculiarities which are important to keep in mind.

So learning WPF requires a lot of raw knowledge of the framework but also experience so you know what is the best approach in a given situation and to get a feeling for what can be done and what cannot.

Comment: I should review those myself.  Good luck as you approach 10k!

Comment: @Rick: Haha, thank you :) (also thanks for the edit, getting late over here, 3am, concentration starts to fail)

Comment: It looks it'll be done with lots of reading after all.
Well thanks :)
I'll see the world perhaps again within the next 10 years or so :P

Comment: @Digital Stone: Yes, have fun!

Answer (score 4):

MVVM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Learn it then use it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful page.

Answer (score 3):

I figured I'd add my $.02 since I've recently started using WPF.  First off, you'll need to read that MVVM article mentioned by Fëanor, and DEAR GOD, download the sample code and learn what every line in that program does!  Reading the article is great, but seeing the code, running it, changing it, etc, is INVALUABLE.  I also echo the comments about the MSDN overviews, and the one about creating a side project rather than learning WPF via an existing project.

Other than that, don't expect to get WPF in a day, or even in a week.  I've been using it for about a month now, and I've still got a ways to go.  I had my "AHA!" moment about a week ago where everything started to click and it became apparent to me what I DIDN'T know which is important.  A good strategy would be for you to pick a single concept such as Data Binding, or Data Templates, or Styles, and explore each in depth.  It's a lot to chew on, so just remember that Rome wasn't built in a day.  And if you're not already comfortable with data binding, I'd pick that up early on since it's pretty crucial.

Lastly, once you learn WPF, it's going to be REALLY hard to go back to using Windows Forms :)

Have Fun!
Q

Comment: I actually didn't write any Windows Forms code or anything like that at all.
All i know is CBM64 Basic, Actionscript, CMD, and HTML+CSS of course.

My problem isn't understanding the overall concepts such as MVVM, and databinding and why that it's important, but indeed the in-depth stuff is, since i only know like 1% of C-sharp, i just took too much on at once i think.

Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that WPF is actually that hard. I think it's just that WPF definitely requires a slightly different way of thinking. You can tell that it was built with certain principles in mind (like MVVM, as another poster mentioned), and it's very different from most other frameworks. If you try to do it like you did Windows Forms or MFC or ASP.NET or whatever... you'll struggle. You need to be willing to change your mind on how things work.

Frankly, I think the only way to learn it is with experimentation. Come up with some side project to work on using WPF and try your hand at it. Learn a bit and refactor it. Get a good book, read the [WPF disciples](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/?pli=1) list, read anything that [Sacha Barber](http://sachabarber.net/) writes, read the [WPF section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) here on SO.

When you have your first "ah ha!" moment where you decide to write an Attached Property to solve some obscure problem you're having, you'll know you've finally understood it :)

Comment: Like i told Quanta, before this i never really touched the modern "new-age" way of programming... other than scripting, which is a whole other game.
So i have no idea what MFC, ASP.NET and all these things even are, so i don't have to 'change' my mindset at all other than scripter/designer-to-developer's mindset :P

Also, i would like to do actually experiment and make my own side-project to help myself with... if i only knew what to type in. See what i'm getting at?

Therefore i am very happy with the links of you and the others!

Comment: So if i understand it correctly, i should at best:

-First learn C# (or at least for the better practical part)

-Learn WPF (including XAML along with it?)

-Then study how to code strong and efficiently such as MVVM-method.

Comment: @Digital Stone - My only change I would make to what you said in your second comment there is that I would make sure to read about MVVM or MVP or similar BEFORE you start learning WPF/XAML. You don't need to go in-depth into it, but just make sure you understand the general concepts. It'll make your life alot easier in understanding why people wrote the WPF/XAML code the way they did when you're looking at examples.

Comment: I see, that sounds logical indeed.
I will beginning learning very soon then, with the knowledge of where to begin.
That's a huge PLUS :)
Thanks a bunch Tim :D

Comment: Good. Now you might want to award someone some points on here or mark something as an answer. Not saying me (I think others had better answers). Just a friendly tip for a new SO user. :)